# Flex2.5 and javascript connection

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, apache-flex

I'm using flex2.5 and javascript. I wonder how to connect between flex and javascript as asynchronous. Or I want to use file browser other way.

flex2.5 as:

```
function A():void{
    var str:string = ExternalInterface.call("start");

    if(str!= null){
        fileref.browse();
    }
}
```

javascript:

```
function start(){
    //other program loading..
    if (end){
        return "end";
    }
}
```

In that case, error is occurred.

> 1) timeout error.. over 15seconds.

so I used setInterval func but that was not solved. because it will be returned method that called `method(function A)` for open the file browser

so I wonder how to call without timer or call `jsp(javascript)` another way
or how to open file browser without any action(click or keydown etc)

Comment: Maybe you find an answer  in this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519112/call-an-adobe-flex-actionscript-method-from-javascript

Comment: I already tried using marshallException.. It doesn't work in Flex2.5....

Answer (score 0):

You can callback to flash when your async process is done.
Here is an example:
[How to call flash actionscript callback method from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657842/how-to-call-flash-actionscript-callback-method-from-javascript)